# Firebase Stripe Extension Not Returning Session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm using the firebase stripe extension to integrate payments into my application. For some reason, when I add an object to the user's sub collection, I'm not redirected to the checkout page. This is because the session Id is never created. What's supposed to happen, from the tutorials I've watched, is that when a document is created in the object_collections, a webhook should be triggered that adds the session ID to the document. The extension is supposed to create the session and hand you back the session ID. For some reason, that is not triggered and I'm not given the session ID. Not sure what to do or how I can debug this.

For the record, I think I did the setup correctly as when I create a new product in the stripe dashboard, it's automatically added to my firestore database.

```
import { collection, getDocs, query, where, addDoc, doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import getStripe from "./initializeStripe";
import { db } from "./firebase-config";

export async function createCheckoutSession(uid) {

    console.log(uid)
    console.log(db)
    const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
    const q = query(usersRef, where("user_id", "==", uid));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
      console.log(`User with UID ${uid} not found`);
      return;
    }
  
    // We assume that there's only one user with the given UID
    const userDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0];

  // Create a new checkout session in the subollection inside this user's document

  const sessionRef = collection(db, "users", userDoc.id, "checkout_sessions");

  const { id: checkoutSessionId } = await addDoc(sessionRef, {
    // replace the price_XXX value with the correct value from your product in stripe.
    price: "price_1MtdiVAFJ9qTOX9QC38xlXRZ",
    success_url: 'pizza.com',
    cancel_url: 'google.com',
  });

  const checkoutSessionRef = doc(sessionRef, checkoutSessionId);
  onSnapshot(checkoutSessionRef, async (snap) => {
    console.log(snap.data())
    const { sessionId } = snap.data();
    console.log(snap.data().sessionId)
    if (snap.exists()) {
      const stripe = await getStripe();
      stripe.redirectToCheckout( {sessionId});
    }
  });
}
```

Edit:

Here is a snapshot of my users collection and the checkout_sessions subcollection.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you notice any error on your Stripe Dashboard request log https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs ?

Comment: @orakaro I just checked and there's no errors but there doesn't seem to be any requests being made in regards to sessions. I created another product and there are post requests made, showing that a new product and price were created.

Comment: If possible can you also share snapshot of your db ?

Comment: @RohitKharche, I figured it out. In my database the document Id of the users object was not the same as the user_id. It redirects to stripe checkout, but doesn't redirect to the success or failure url.